# FFTW signal spectrum

Tags: c++, signals, fft, fftw, spectrum

I am currently working on implementing signal spectrum chart.
My input data: 1.051, 1.365, 1.837, 2.334, 2.486, 2.688, 2.878, 2.579, 2.11, 1.605, 0.936, 0.73, 1.036, 1.336, 1.796, 2.043, 2.462, 2.935, 2.892, 2.609, 2.151, 1.641, 0.961, 0.738, 0.767, 1.303, 1.503, 2.004, 2.435, 2.931, 2.908, 2.641, 1.935, 1.423, 0.988, 0.747, 0.755, 1.018, 1.465, 1.966, 2.662, 2.919, 2.918, 2.669, 1.976, 1.462, 1.017, 0.757, 0.746, 0.989, 1.426, 1.927, 2.637, 2.908, 2.927, 2.441, 2.015, 1.501, 1.302, 1.025, 0.739, 0.962, 1.644, 2.144, 2.605, 2.895, 2.935, 2.467, 2.304, 1.797, 1.331, 1.039, 0.732, 0.936, 1.608, 2.103, 2.575, 2.88, 2.688, 2.493, 2.343, 1.835, 1.365, 1.054, 0.725, 0.913, 1.568, 2.067, 2.288, 2.867, 2.69, 2.516, 2.379, 1.877, 1.397, 1.072, 0.721, 1.144, 1.277, 1.77

You can see this data on my screenshot. It is bottom chart. It contains only 100 points. And it is impossible to increase its amount.

Input signal frequency is 1000 Hz. And it can be changed.

I use FFTW to get spectrum.

Input signal frequency is 1000 Hz. On the top chart it shows only about 200 Hz. That's the main problem. I suppose that maybe my code is wrong or amount of points is not enough.

my code for data analyzing:

```
    QVectorDouble points(100);
    points = this->reader->ReadCOM(100);
    double timePassed = this->reader->timePassed;
    unsigned int n = points.count();
    double timeShift = timePassed / n;

    QVectorDouble signalX(n), signalY(n);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        signalX[i] = i*timeShift; // x goes from 0 to  timePassed to take points amount
        signalY[i] = points[i];
    }

    fftw::maxthreads = get_max_threads();
    unsigned int np = n / 2 + 1;
    size_t align = sizeof(Complex);

    array1<Complex> F(np, align);
    array1<double> f(n, align);

    rcfft1d Forward(n, f, F);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = points[i];
    }

    Forward.fft(f, F);

    QVectorDouble spectrX(np), spectrY(np);
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
    {
      spectrX[i] = i * 20; //multiply by 20 because np is (100/2 + 1) and chart maximum xOrigin is 1000
      spectrY[i] = abs(F[i]) / np;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "Am I doing right" is quite broad - do you have evidence that there is/isn't a specific problem?

Comment: input signal frequency is 1000 Hz. On the ttop chart it shows only about 200 Hz. that's the main problem) I suppose that maybe my code is wrong or amount of points is not enough.

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to change the units on the x-axis of your fft plot. Right now it appears as if you are plotting the fft bin number where in reality you would want to plot the frequency of that specific bin.

Comment: @TarasNikulin It appears that the OP is running a length 1024 fft and using the bin number as the x-axis

Comment: @AlexZywicki 1000 it is range, that i setted up by myself

Comment: How is the input signal being generated? Also It doesn't appear that you are  even running your signal through the FFT. From what I can see you are running you `points` through the fft and not `signalX` or `signalY`

Comment: I have function generator, which signal i pass to ADC on the "Development Board UNI-DS3 by Mikroelektronika", than i save 100 points into buff, than i pass them to Serial port. Processor on development board is Intel 8051

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few things that aren't quite right:

- In the time-domain plot, 100 points at a sampling rate of 1000Hz should give you a total duration of 0.1 second. The formula used for `signalX` is correct assuming that `timePassed` is 0.1 second. You should look into why that variable is actually around 0.4 second.
- Since you have 8 complete cycles in 0.1 seconds, you should get a peak frequency of 8*1/0.1 = 80Hz. So, clearly something is wrong with the x-axis scaling of the spectrogram. More specifically, the frequency increments should be set to `1000/np` or 10Hz with `np == 10`. That will generate a plot up to 500Hz which is half the sampling rate (consistent with Nyquist theorem), where the peak will show up at the correct 80Hz frequency.